# Adding CRC to packet somehow breaks CryptoJS's AES

Tags: javascript, encryption, appcelerator, bouncycastle, cryptojs

I am writing a mobile app in javascript (with appcelerator) that communicates with a server app written in Java. 
The communication is encrypted.

Now I want to implement integrity checking via CRC on the client (the server side is finished already by another party). 
While the CRC gets computed correctly, something seems to break the encryption process. It's very strange behaviour and I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

The server uses bouncycastles for decryption.

The client sends javascript objects to the server in the following way:

- The object gets converted to a json string
- This then gets converted to a byteArray (Titanium.Buffer to be precise) - I'll call this: content
- A header gets added with the following information:

  - 5 Bytes specify the packet type
  - 4 bytes for the length of the content
  - 4 bytes for a CRC32 of the header
  - 4 bytes for a CRC32 of the content
- the content gets appended to the header - I'll call this: packet
- the packet gets encrypted via cryptoJS AES in CBC mode
- the encrypted packet gets a header (via the same method as the one before)
- this gets sent to the server

The server then throws an exception:

```
bsc.sdk.security.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
at bsc.sdk.security.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding.padCount(PKCS7Padding.java:62)
at bsc.sdk.security.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.java:273)
at bsc.sdk.api.crypt.aes.AESCipher.doFinal(AESCipher.java:60)
at bsc.sdk.api.crypt.aes.AESCipher.decrypt(AESCipher.java:36)
```

Now here's where the fun part starts: The exception only happens when the header CRC lies in a certain range. 
I tested this by manually writing integers around the original CRC into the header block. It fails when the integer is somewhere around the range between 1963000000 and 1963990000. These numbers are probably not exactly accurate but I didn't test further due to time constraints.

When I write some other Int like for example 2534528925 into the block, everything's fine.

So, does anyone have an idea why certain CRCs seem to break the padding of the AES algorithm?

Here are relevant code snippets of the client (if you need more, just ask):

```
send: function (command, ) {

    var commandString = JSON.stringify(command, null);
    var commandBuffer = Ti.createBuffer({value: commandString});
    var packageBuffer = this.setHeader(commandBuffer, 2);

    // encrypt and reassign the header
    var encrypted = EncryptionService.encrypt(packageBuffer);
    var words = encrypted.words;
    var encryptedWordsCount = words.length;
    var encryptedBuffer = Ti.createBuffer({length: encryptedWordsCount * 4});

    for (i = 0; i < encryptedWordsCount; i++) {

        Ti.Codec.encodeNumber({
            source: words[i],
            dest: encryptedBuffer,
            position: i * 4,
            type: Ti.Codec.TYPE_INT,
            byteOrder: Ti.Codec.BIG_ENDIAN
        });
    }

    packageBuffer = this.setHeader(encryptedBuffer, 1);            
    Ti.Stream.write(this.socket, packageBuffer, this.writeCallback);  
}

setHeader: function (commandBuffer, type) {

    var commandBufferLength = commandBuffer.length;
    var paddedCommandBufferLength = this.options.headerLength + commandBuffer.length;

    var type = (!type || type == 2) ? 0x00000002 : ((type == 1) ? 0x00000001 : 0x00000000);


    var buffer = Ti.createBuffer({
        length: this.options.headerLength
    });

    // write sync byte
    Ti.Codec.encodeNumber({
        source: 0x55,
        dest: buffer,
        position: 0,
    type: Ti.Codec.TYPE_BYTE,
    byteOrder: Ti.Codec.BIG_ENDIAN
    });

    // write the type
    Ti.Codec.encodeNumber({
        source: type,
        dest: buffer,
        position: 1,
        type: Ti.Codec.TYPE_INT,
        byteOrder: Ti.Codec.BIG_ENDIAN
    });

    // write the contentLength
    Ti.Codec.encodeNumber({
        source: commandBufferLength,
        dest: buffer,
        position: 5,
        type: Ti.Codec.TYPE_INT,
        byteOrder: Ti.Codec.BIG_ENDIAN
    });
    computeChecksumFromByteArray(headerBuffer, buffer, 9, this.crcTable);

    buffer.append(commandBuffer);

    return buffer; 
}

    computeChecksumFromByteArray: function(array, destinationBuffer, destinationOffset, crcTable){
    var crc = -1; 

    for(var i=0, l=array.length; i<l; i++)
    {
        crc = crc >>> 8 ^ crcTable[ crc & 255 ^ array[i] ];
    }
    crc = (crc ^ -1) >>> 0;

    Ti.Codec.encodeNumber({
        source: crc,
        dest: destinationBuffer,
        position: destinationOffset,
        type: Ti.Codec.TYPE_INT,
        byteOrder: Ti.Codec.BIG_ENDIAN
    }); 
}

EncryptionService.encrypt : function(buffer) {

    var key = App.authentication.sharedSecret;

    var bufferLength = buffer.length;
    var bufferHexString = App.Library.Helper.createHexString(buffer);
    var bufferWords = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(bufferHexString);
    var options = {
        iv : CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000'),
        padding : CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    };

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(bufferWords, key, options);

    return encrypted.ciphertext;

}
```

Comment: When the server throws an exception due to bad padding, can the client tell from the server response that the problem is bad padding? If so, you have a padding oracle, which is very bad and completely insecure. For more info, cf. for example http://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/

Comment: Your CryptoJS code looks fine aside from not authenticating your ciphertext. Perhaps there is a problem with the encoding of your crc. Are you sure it fits into the space you're allotted it to? (I haven't looked at that code in detail)

Comment: Jim Flood: No, it can't. I have the server running here as well for testing purposes. That's where I get the exception from. But thanks!

Comment: Artjom: Yes, I am sure. The CRC is an Int (32 bit) and I'm putting it in 4 Bytes.
Also, like I said: The problem seems to only happen when the CRC is in a certain range (given above). Even bigger Ints work flawlessly.